# Detect charset encoding and line feed code for given file in java

Tags: java, character-encoding

I want to get file encoding type and the line feed code.

I am using Java 6.

As I have used following third-party library also 
but this library not give me 100% guaranteed result.

1. jmimemagic
2. droid
3. Apache Tika
4. Simple Magic
5. mime util

I have also tested all solution from below question, but still it not give me guaranteed solution.

How to get Line feed code?
As there are different line feed code like

1. CRLF (Windows)
2. LF (Unix)
3. CR (Old Mac)

So from above which code is used for new line in file.

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution:

We can use "nkf32.dll" to detect the character encoding using JNA or JNI.

nkf32.dll is Network Kanji Filter which basically deal with character encoding and it's conversion

We can also convert to different Line Feed Code.

Reference:
       http://www.vector.co.jp/soft/win95/util/se020949.html

There is also tool "FCChecker" which can detect:

```
 1. Character Encoding
 2. Line Feed code
```

and also perform conversion.

Ref: http://www.vector.co.jp/soft/dl/winnt/util/se478635.html